# I want to create a file and stored in HTTPS path below file is working for local storge can you help me on how to store file http path?

Tags: java

I want to create a file and stored in HTTPS path below file is working for local storge can you help me on how to store file http path?

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\output\\"sample".CSV"));
```

Comment: https? What do you mean?

Comment: I created a file and stored in local path using:

pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\output\\"test".CSV"));
But if tried to store a file in HTTP path  (http://sitesearch/) I'm getting a file not found error even though I have access to the HTTP path.

Answer (score 0):

You want to save some data in a file on a remote server that is offering some https endpoint.

This is very different from saving a file in a local filesystem

You need to know what the remote service is expecting. There are multiple ways of transferring data to a web service.

In general, a web-based service that accepts data and stores it is likely to require some kind of authentication -- is that true in this case?

Once you know the details of the protocol the server is expecting, you will need to open a network connection to the remote server and transfer the data. You will want to use an existing library to do that -- something like Apache HttpComponents https://hc.apache.org/

Comment: I created a file and stored in local path using:

pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\output\\"test".CSV"));
But if tried to store a file in HTTP path  (http://sitesearch/) I'm getting a file not found error even though I have access to the HTTP path.

Comment: "store a file in HTTP path" is not a thing. You store a file in a filesystem, not in HTTP paths, or cats, or shoeboxes.